# SQLite RANDOM() function in CTE

Tags: sqlite, random, common-table-expression

I found behavior of RANDOM() function in SQLite, which doesn't seems correct.

I want to generate random groups using random RANDOM() and CASE. However, it looks like CTE is not behaving in a correct way.

[image: Expectation vs Reality]

First, let's create a table

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tt10ROWS;
CREATE TEMP TABLE tt10ROWS (
    some_int INTEGER);

INSERT INTO tt10ROWS VALUES
    (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10);
SELECT * FROM tt10ROWS;
```

[image: Table #1]

**Incorrect behaviour**

```
WITH 
    -- 2.a add columns with random number and save in CTE
    STEP_01 AS (
        SELECT
            *,
            ABS(RANDOM()) % 4 + 1 AS RAND_1_TO_4
        FROM tt10ROWS)
        
    -- 2.b - get random group
select
    *,
    CASE 
        WHEN RAND_1_TO_4 = 1 THEN 'GROUP_01'
        WHEN RAND_1_TO_4 = 2 THEN 'GROUP_02'
        WHEN RAND_1_TO_4 = 3 THEN 'GROUP_03'
        WHEN RAND_1_TO_4 = 4 THEN 'GROUP_04' 
        END AS GROUP_IT
from STEP_01;
```

Using such query we get a table, which generates correct values for RAND_1_TO_4 columns, but GROUP_IT column is incorrect. We can see, that groups don't match and some groups even missing.

**Correct behaviour**

I found a walkaround for such problem by creating a temporary table instead of using CTE. It helped.

```
-- 1.a - add column with random number 1-4 and save as TEMP TABLE
drop table if exists ttSTEP01;
CREATE TEMP TABLE ttSTEP01 AS
        SELECT
            *,
            ABS(RANDOM()) % 4 + 1 AS RAND_1_TO_4
        FROM tt10ROWS;

-- 1.b - get random group
select
    *,
    CASE 
        WHEN RAND_1_TO_4 = 1 THEN 'GROUP_01'
        WHEN RAND_1_TO_4 = 2 THEN 'GROUP_02'
        WHEN RAND_1_TO_4 = 3 THEN 'GROUP_03'
        WHEN RAND_1_TO_4 = 4 THEN 'GROUP_04' 
        END AS GROUP_IT
from ttSTEP01;
```

**QUESTION**

What is the reasons behind such behaviour, where GROUP_IT column is not generated properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the bytecode generated by the incorrect query using [`EXPLAIN`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_explain.html), you'll see that every time the `RAND_1_TO_4` column is referenced, its value is re-calculated and a new random number is used (I suspect but aren't 100% sure this has something to do with how `random()` is a non-deterministic function). The null values are for those times when none of the `CASE` tests end up being true.

When you insert into a temporary table and then use that for the rest, the values of course remain static and it works as expected.

Comment: *The null values are for those times when none of the CASE tests end up being true* if `RAND_1_TO_4` is recalculated each time it is referenced (which seems to be the case here), it *should* be recalculated  as  `ABS(RANDOM()) % 4 + 1` so there shouldn't be any `null`s in the result. Since there are `null`s this means that the recalculation is not done as it *should*. This smells like a bug.

Comment: @forpas Suppose it ends up 4=1, 3=2, 2=3, 1=4. All of those are false and since there's no blanket else at the end, case returns null.

Comment: Also see [this old thread from 2008](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/problem-using-random-in-queries-td41923.html). Opinions were mixed on if it's a bug or not and I suspect drh filed it as wontfix.

Comment: You are right about the nulls and by just changing the syntax of CASE so  that RAND_1_TO_4 is referenced only once, the nulls are removed: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=6bbc19c749a0c4bfe54bfe915eddfa78