# SQLite recalculates random() multiple times in subquery or CTE

Tags: sqlite, random, subquery, common-table-expression

If I run the following query:

```sql
WITH cte AS(SELECT random() AS rand)
SELECT rand,rand FROM cte;
```

the value `rand` is calculated once, and the same value appears twice in in the result.

If I run that with a table:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS data;
CREATE TABLE data(n int);
INSERT INTO data(n) VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5);
WITH cte AS(SELECT random() AS rand FROM data)
SELECT rand,rand FROM cte;
```

or, if you prefer with a recursive CTE:

```sql
WITH 
    data AS (SELECT 1 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 1+n FROM data WHERE n<5),
    cte AS(SELECT random() AS rand FROM data)
SELECT rand,rand FROM cte;
```

… the value for `rand` is recalculated for every instance, and so each row in the result set has two different values. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/73fd4/1

I expected `random()` to be recalculated for each row, but I didn’t expect expect that the `rand` value be recalculated after the CTE.

I don’t think this is standard behaviour, and it certainly isn’t how PostgreSQL, SQL Server and MySQL work.

How do I get SQLite to calculate the `rand` value only once per iteration?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64328853/sqlite-random-function-in-cte

Answer (score 0):

I can offer you the following workaround which behaves the way you want:

```sql
WITH data AS (
    SELECT 1 AS n, random() AS rand
    UNION ALL SELECT 1 + n, random()
    FROM data WHERE n < 5
)

SELECT rand, rand FROM data;
```

### Demo

This approach just turns out the calls to `random()` directly inside your recursive CTE.  For whatever reason, SQLite does not seem to get too smart for itself and try to cache away an initial call to `random()`.

Comment: I shouldn’t have included the recursive CTE. What I really wanted to do was to set a random value for each row of a real table, and then to use that value multiple times. It is odd, however, that putting `random()` in the CTE evaluates once, but not with a real table.

Comment: @Manngo ... if using a CTE gets around the problem, then it is at least a valid solution.