# Materialized CTE in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, optimization, common-table-expression

[SQLite 3.35.0](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_35_0.html) includes support for [materialized CTEs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html#mathint),

> If the MATERIALIZED phrase is used, then select-stmt is likely evaluated to generate an ephemeral table that is held in memory or a temporary disk file, to be used in place of the CTE table name whenever that table name appears in the subsequent SQL. Because the select-stmt is evaluated immediately, the opportunity to apply optimizations such as query flattening or the push-down optimization, is lost. (The CTE then acts as an "optimization fence".)

I want to construct an example to understand the new behavior, and came up with the following query

```sql
WITH foo AS MATERIALIZED (
    SELECT RANDOM() FROM (SELECT 1)
) SELECT * FROM foo a, foo b;
```

With the `MATERIALIZED` hint, the CTE should be stored in a temporary table, but the result contains two distinct numbers, suggesting that `foo` is evaluated twice.

```
-1208936393171353997|288817028780076083
```

Here is the query plan. Surprisingly, playing with `(NOT) MATERIALIZED` doesn't seem to have any effect.

```
addr  opcode         p1    p2    p3    p4             p5  comment
----  -------------  ----  ----  ----  -------------  --  -------------
0     Init           0     1     0                    0
1     Integer        8     1     0                    0
2     Once           0     8     0                    0
3     OpenEphemeral  2     1     0                    0
4     Integer        1     2     0                    0
5     MakeRecord     2     1     3                    0
6     NewRowid       2     4     0                    0
7     Insert         2     3     4                    8
8     Return         1     0     0                    0
9     Integer        16    5     0                    0
10    Once           0     16    0                    0
11    OpenEphemeral  3     1     0                    0
12    Integer        1     6     0                    0
13    MakeRecord     6     1     7                    0
14    NewRowid       3     8     0                    0
15    Insert         3     7     8                    8
16    Return         5     0     0                    0
17    Rewind         2     24    0                    0
18      Rewind         3     24    0                    0
19        Function       0     0     9     random(0)      0
20        Function       0     0     10    random(0)      0
21        ResultRow      9     2     0                    0
22      Next           3     19    0                    1
23    Next           2     18    0                    1
24    Halt           0     0     0                    0
```

Why is the CTE not materialized? As a bonus, can you construct a query with different behavior under SQLite 3.35.0 and prior versions (e.g. convert a random number generator into [`getRandomNumber`](https://xkcd.com/221/) by materializing it, just like what I'm trying to achieve here)?

Comment: *Applications should not depend upon the semantic effects of this hint with respect to when or how often user-defined functions are called.*

Comment: What sqlite does with non-deterministic functions like `random()` can be pretty counter intuitive sometimes. Seeing the bytecode produced by that query (See `EXPLAIN`) would be useful.

Comment: @Shawn I see where you are coming from, but SQLite takes backward compatibility very seriously (they even keep legacy compatibility with bugs in prior versions), so I'm interested in finding out if the change in implementation may break anything. I constructed the query with `RANDOM` on purpose to exploit its quirky behavior. The query plan will be included in a moment :)

Comment: Yeah, it's not saving the random values in the temp table (Just rowids) - probably because they're non-deterministic. Storing them would indeed break compatibility with the behavior of a CTE that leaves out the materialized hint - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64328853/sqlite-random-function-in-cte) for an example of how `random()` interacts with CTEs.

Comment: @nalzok . .  My guess is that this is an undocumented feature that avoids the materialization when the CTE is really simple.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `random()` is a non-deterministic function. It's allowed to (And does) return a different value every time it's called. Sqlite doesn't cache the results of such functions - instead, the function is called again each time it's referenced. You can see that in the bytecode of your query and how it's being called in the join at the end, not in the creation of the ephemeral table that's used to hold the manifested rowids.

If it did cache the random numbers in those tables, the behavior of the query would be different between materialized and non-materialized versions, which is contrary to the idea that they're just optimization hints - the values returned by the two versions of a CTE should be equivalent and behave the same way.

As the [documentation](http://sqlite.org/lang_with.html) at the end of the Materialized section notes,

> Applications should not depend upon the semantic effects of this hint with respect to when or how often user-defined functions are called.

If you want the randomly-generated number to stay the same every time a given row is referenced, you need a real temporary table, not a CTE.

Comment: . . Where is that snippet of documentation?  The actual documentation on `MATERIALIZE` (https://sqlite.org/lang_with.html) has no mention of non-deterministic functions and is quite clear that the results of the CTE are stored and re-used.  This is not about caching the results of the function.  It is about storing the results of the materialized view.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It's in the page you and OP linked.

Comment: The odd thing is that the cte is being materialized twice, though that might be necessary because of the self join. I don't know if it supports multiple iterators into the same table.

Comment: . . That seems to be in direct contradiction of the rest of the section, except that it is all caveated:  "is **likely** evaluated".  I think SQLite needs better documentation writers.  It sounds like both `MATERIALIZED` and `NOT MATERIALIZED` are merely suggestions -- making one wonder if there is any difference at all between the two.  I upvoted, but I wonder if this is due to the presence of the function or just such a simple CTE that SQLite foregoes materialization.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Materialization is explicitly described as a "non-binding hint". So, yes, they are merely suggestions.